# How to suppress comma list from outputting its values on declaration?

Tags: expl3, latex3, comma-separated-list, variable

I need to suppress the display of the comma list on its declaration. I just need comma-list variable to store the list, not display it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \clist_new:N\myVar{one,two} % displays one,two
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `:N` signature of the function tells you that the argument of `\clist_new:N` is one single token. The function just creates an empty `⟨clist var⟩`; it does not assign contents to it.

In fact, if you use `\clist_show:N` (or `\clist_log:N`) you'll see that `\myVar` is empty:

```latex
\clist_new:N \myVar {one,two}
\clist_show:N \myVar
```

this shows in the terminal:

```
The comma list \myVar is empty
> .
```

You need to first create the variable with `\clist_new:N`, then add contents to it with `\clist_set:Nn` (which takes two arguments; the first, `N`, a single token, in this case, the `⟨clist var⟩`, and the second, `n`, an argument enclosed in braces, which is the contents):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \myVar
\clist_set:Nn \myVar {one,two}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Then, if you try to `\clist_show:N` you'll see:

```
The comma list \myVar contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {one}
>  {two}.
```